# Unable to append multiple data frame with a loop function - Only returns empty Data Frame | Pandas, Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, append

I got my data with web-scrape using the following code:

```
import requests
import re
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import unquote
from json import loads
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Download URL
url = "https://riwayat-file-covid-19-dki-jakarta-jakartagis.hub.arcgis.com/"
req = requests.get(url)

# Get encoded JSON from HTML source
encoded_data = re.search("window\.__SITE=\"(.*)\"", req.text).groups()[0]

# Decode and load as dictionary
json_data = loads(unquote(encoded_data))

# Get the HTML source code for the links
html_src = json_data["site"]["data"]["values"]["layout"]["sections"][1]["rows"][0]["cards"][0]["component"]["settings"]["markdown"]

# Parse it using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_src, 'html.parser')

# Get links
links = soup.find_all('a')

# For each link...
link_list = []
id_list = []
date_list = []
dataframe_csv = []

for link in links:
    if "2021" in link.text:
       link_list.append(link.text+" - "+link.attrs['href'])

link_list.remove("31 Januari 2021 Pukul 10.00 - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vd1tToQbx3A420KMDA63aKviLjgGPJMd/view?usp=sharing")

for i in link_list:
    id_list.append(i.split("/")[5])
    date_list.append(i.split("/")[0][:-21])
    
for ID in id_list:
    dataframe_csv.append("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/"+ID+"/export?format=csv")
```

I want to append multiple data frames into an empty data frame "df_total" using a loop function. Inside the loop, I want to remove row index 0 in every data frame, and add a new column called "Date". I use the following code:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()

df_total = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0, len(dataframe_csv)):
    df = pd.read_csv(dataframe_csv[i])
    df = df.drop(index=df.index[0], axis=0)
    df = df.assign(Date = date_list[i])
        
    df_total.append(df,ignore_index=True)

elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print(elapsed_time)
```

The problem is, the code above does work but the data frame "df_total" does not seems to be appended by any data frame that I read with pandas during the loop. I tried to see the dimension of the data frame with the following code:

```
df_total.shape
```

The code above returns the value (0,0) meaning that the data frame "df_total" is still empty.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer to this problem. So I can use the following code:

```
import time

start_time = time.time()

df_total = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0, len(dataframe_csv)):
    df = pd.read_csv(dataframe_csv[i])
    df = df.drop(index=df.index[0], axis=0)
    df = df.assign(Date = date_list[i])
    df_total = df_total.append(df, ignore_index = True)
    print(f"Merging a total of {i} Data Frames - Total Rows = {len(df_total)}")
    
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
print(elapsed_time/60)
```

Notice that I forgot to assign the appended Data Frame in my previous code. Now the code successfully merged into one huge Data Frame. I also added a print function so that I am able to track how many Data Frames are being merged at a particular moment. This way, I am able to know where is the merging process is at.